# How to run OpenCV real-time object recognition in the background on Android

Tags: android, opencv

I managed to create an App that recognize objects in real-time but now I'm really struggling how to run this in the background when for example user will press the home button and try to run another App. I'm using OpenCV and my solution is based on Face Detection example where you train your Cascade Classifier, all coded in Java. Any suggestions? Many thx.

Comment: What have you tried? Have your read about android services? If that didn't work, why?